# How to rename/alias a function in C?

Tags: c, function, alias

Say I have a library I am making and I want to call a function `rename` or `puts`, how can I keep the original `rename` and `puts` from `stdlib` or `stdio` or whatever, and yet have my own function be `puts`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

alias puts original_puts;

void
puts(char *c) {
  original_puts(c);
}
```

How can I accomplish *something to this effect*?

Comment: Aside: The signature for `puts()` is `int puts(const char *s);`. Recommend the same for any alias to not break the code base.

Comment: Search for “function interposition”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't alias library functions, but you can alias your own using preprocessor directives.

For example:

mylib.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void my_puts(char *c);

#define puts(arg) my_puts(arg)
```

mylib.c:

```
void my_puts(char *c)
{
    (puts)(c);
}
```

Now, anytime someone calls `puts`, it substitutes a call to `my_puts` instead.  Also, when you want to call the "real" function in your wrapper, you can put the function name in quotes.  Because the macro that does the substitution is a function-like macro, the parenthesis prevent the substitution from happening.

Comment: I would like to have it be when you do `#include <mylib.h>`, when you use `puts(x)`, it does what my `puts` does, not the `stdlib`. Basically, I want to wrap `puts` with `myputs`, but have `puts` in userland be `myputs`. Can this be done with what you're saying, or another way?

Comment: but if you ado this the original puts will not be available.,

Comment: @LancePollard do you want the original puts to be callable or you do not care

Comment: I don't care if the original is callable, no. I want to be able to call the original _within my wrapper_, but that's it. It doesn't need to be callable elsewhere.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Actually, that would be better.  I was thinking about `printf`.  Edited.

Comment: @LancePollard That's what this does.  It takes any call to `puts` in your code and changes it into a call to `my_puts` instead.

Comment: @Gerhardh I knew there was some way to do that but forgot the exact syntax. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

If compiling with `gcc` or `clang`, you can wrap the symbol with `-Wl,--wrap`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int __real_puts(const char *c);
int __wrap_puts(const char *c) {
        __real_puts("Hello");
        __real_puts(c);
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
        puts("world");
}
```

```
$ gcc src.c -Wl,--wrap=puts && ./a.out
Hello
world
```

Comment: What about with `clang`, I am using `clang` as it turns out :)

Comment: Well, `clang` didn't complain

Comment: Clang is, by design, gcc compatible as much as possible. Their documentation says so.

Comment: @LancePollard it works also in clang, at least on version 10: https://godbolt.org/z/eyE9z-